# Ошибка статичности

Tags: c#

При использовании:

```
public static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Refresh();
}
```

Выдает:

> Ошибка    CS0120  Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства
>   "Form1.webBrowser1" требуется ссылка на объект.   Form1.cs 101

Если вместо `webBrowser1` подставить `Form1.webBrowser1`, то тоже не работает.

P.S 
`webBrowser1` имеет модификатор `public`

Если убрать `static`, то ошибка убирается, но теперь из-за этого не вызывается сама функция с аналогичной ошибкой.

Comment: Если функция собирается пользоваться нестатическим полем, то она сама, понятно, должна быть тоже нестатической. Уберите `static` у функции и покажите вызывающий код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему можно попробовать решить следующим образом.

Привести первый параметр метода к типу формы и обращаться к нестатическому полю через него. Например:

```
public static void MyStaticMethod(Object source)
{
    ((Form1)source).webBrowser1.Refresh();
}
```

Естественно, что в этот метод должен так или иначе передаваться **существующий** объект формы.